# Using lightning:listView in VF page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, aura

I am trying to embed standard lightning:listView into the VF. The list view shows up as expected but when I click on the record it does not navigate to the record detail page.

VisualForce page

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
            
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:MediaListView",
              { },
              "lightning",
              function(cmp) {
                console.log("component was created");
                // do some stuff
              }
          );
        });
    
   
    </script>
 
</apex:page>
```

Lightning app:

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="lightning:listView"/>
    <aura:dependency resource="c:MediaListView"/>
</aura:application>
```

Aura CMP:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable">
    <lightning:listView aura:id="listViewAccounts"
    objectApiName="scormanywhere__Course__c"
    listName="scormanywhere__All"
    rows="50"
    showSearchBar="true"
    showActionBar="true"
    enableInlineEdit="true"
    showRowLevelActions="true"
/>
</aura:component>
```

There is a callback function missing on the visualforce page; however, I cannot find any document or resource on how to add function in the visualforce page.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most events that cause navigation or other effects *outside* the boundary of a component are handled by the `one.app` container, i.e., the Lightning Experience. When you run components in a Lightning Out context with Visualforce, the page context that would handle those events is not present, and as a result they do nothing.

In this case, note that [`<lightning:listView>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:listView/documentation) is not supported in Lightning Out:

> **Experience**
> Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, Salesforce Mobile App

It's possible that you might be able to build a solution by catching navigation events yourself and handling them, but be advised that you're trying something that is explicitly unsupported, and the exact method by which this component signals navigation events is not documented. (It could be [`<force:navigateToSObject>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToSObject/documentation), but it might not be).